# PHPExcel formula causing false column identifier

Tags: php, phpexcel

Slightly strange problem I'm having. Whilst looping through rows and columns in an excel spreadsheet, if a cell has a formula, it treats that as a different column. For example:

```
$c = 0;
foreach ($objWorksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
    $c++;
    foreach ($row->getCellIterator() as $cell) {
        $cellValue = trim($cell->getCalculatedValue());
        if ($cell->getColumn() == "N" || $cell->getColumn() == "O") {
            var_dump("ROW: $c . Get column: " . $cell->getColumn());
            var_dump("ROW: $c . Cell value: " . $cellValue);
        }
    }
}
```

There's a header, and one row in a spreadsheet I'm using for testing. Based on the if statement, it should only var_dump data from column "N" and "O", but it is infact outputting 9 additional times. The spreadsheet contains 9 cells that have formula in them, containing conditionals for "N" and "O". Output:

```
string(46) "ROW: 2 . Get column: N"
string(48) "ROW: 2 . Cell value: TEST N COLUMN"
string(46) "ROW: 2 . Get column: O"
string(53) "ROW: 2 . Cell value: TEST O COLUMN"
string(46) "ROW: 2 . Get column: O"
string(45) "ROW: 2 . Cell value: "
string(46) "ROW: 2 . Get column: O"
string(59) "ROW: 2 . Cell value: "
string(46) "ROW: 2 . Get column: O"
string(45) "ROW: 2 . Cell value: "
string(46) "ROW: 2 . Get column: O"
string(45) "ROW: 2 . Cell value: "
string(46) "ROW: 2 . Get column: O"
string(45) "ROW: 2 . Cell value: "
string(46) "ROW: 2 . Get column: O"
string(45) "ROW: 2 . Cell value: "
string(46) "ROW: 2 . Get column: O"
string(45) "ROW: 2 . Cell value: "
string(46) "ROW: 2 . Get column: O"
string(45) "ROW: 2 . Cell value: "
string(46) "ROW: 2 . Get column: O"
string(45) "ROW: 2 . Cell value: "
```

I'm not too familiar with Excel, but the formula in the 9 columns that seem to be outputted is something like this:

```
=IF(AF2="YES", N2&O2&"FR/BL"," ")
```

So as you can see column "N2" and "O2" are being used, but it's causing issues with the getColumn function in PHPExcel. The columns with this formula are AG, AJ, AM, AP, AS, AV, AY, BB, BE, but I don't think this should matter.

Help please!

### Update

If I copy and paste the row but paste only the values, it works. However, $cellValue uses getCalculatedValue anyway, so I don't understand why this doesn't solve the problem....hmm

Comment: You have syntax errors in var_dump() parameters. Check double quotes.

Comment: Yeah, there are no errors in the actual code, just mistyping here! I'll edit.

Comment: I thought I'd put in a fix to resolve this issue six months or so ago, what version of PHPExcel are you using?

Comment: @MarkBaker perhaps that's it. Using 1.7.9-dev

Comment: @MarkBaker, 1.8.0 doesn't work, I'll try dev-master

Comment: In that case, I think you'll need to wait for a patch... I thought I'd done that fix before the 1.8.0 release, but obviously haven't... so it probably hasn't been committed to github

Comment: @MarkBaker Ok cheers, fyi it isn't working/available for 1.7.9, 1.8.0, dev-master, or 2.0.0-dev.

Comment: I've just committed/pushed the bugfix for this issue to the develop branch on github

Comment: @MarkBaker, cheers, I'll test today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bugfix to ensure that current cell is maintained when executing formula calculations

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/commit/87be8d3d8e1c503a6422fee585e5fc5193c66978

Updating to "dev-develop" branch using composer fixed the issue.